# Migrated question - user mismatched

Tags: bug, status-completed

[Take this question as an example](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14210/is-socialtrend-com-or-and-feelthetrend-com-legitimate). A question was migrated to Money, while the user wasn't active on the site. The user followed the question, but it wasn't matched to him. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I investigated this and it should resolve itself after a little bit of time automatically.  To support the automatic recovery, the accounts need to be linked and use the same email address for both sites.

Comment: I manually associated the user with his post. This is [tag:status-completed] now. :)